# Google Cloud Vision API -" image-annotator::Malformed request.: Image processing error"

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika, google-cloud-vision

I am getting an error while querying Google Vision API:

```
 {
      "responses" : [ {
        "error" : {
          "code" : 3,
          "message" : "image-annotator::Malformed request.: Image processing error!"
        }
      } ]
    }
```

I have passed a pdf file which contains images and then extracted image using `pdfbox` to create `AnnotateImageRequest` list

```
List<AnnotateImageRequest> visionRequests = new ArrayList<>();
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfDatastream);
for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
    PDResources resources = page.getResources();
    for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
        PDXObject pdxObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
            if (pdxObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                byte[] imageArray = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(((PDImageXObject) pdxObject).createInputStream()));
                System.out.println("image >>"+imageArray.length);
                Image image = new Image();
                image.encodeContent(imageArray);

                Feature feature = new Feature();
                feature.setType("TEXT_DETECTION");

                AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();
                annotateImageRequest.setImage(image);
                annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(feature));
                visionRequests.add(annotateImageRequest);
            }
    }
}
```

And passed the list created above to vision service :

```
BatchAnnotateImagesResponse visionSrvcResponse = visionSrvc.images().annotate(new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest().setRequests(visionRequests)).execute();
System.out.println(visionSrvcResponse.toPrettyString());
```

I have also tried removing the base64 encoding of image bytearray, but still get the same error listed on the top.The bytearray length is "*774800*"

**Is there something which I am missing because when I multipart an image to the servlet and pass the bytearray obtained from the inputstream it works fine.**

I am running the application on Tomcat V8

dependecies used :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-vision</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev24-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `PDImageXObject.createInputStream()` delivers the raw pixel data without any size information. Is this what this google API needs? PDFBox can also return a `BufferedImage` with `PDImageXObject.getImage()`, you can then save this one with ImageIO.write() to a stream. EncodeContent does not explain what it needs. https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/Image.html#encodeContent(byte[])

Comment: I am unaware of internal details. I too saw the same javadoc and then encoded the image stream using `com.google.api.client.util.Base64`.

Comment: Can you try what I mentioned in my 1st comment or do you need some code? The idea is that you write in a ByteArrayOutputStream, then take the byte array from there, then do the encode64 stuff you already do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr)

I changed my code as per his suggestion and it works:

```
if (pdxObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( ((PDImageXObject) pdxObject).getImage(), "jpg", baos );
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

    Image image = new Image();
    image.encodeContent(imageInByte);

    Feature feature = new Feature();
    feature.setType("TEXT_DETECTION");

    AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();
    annotateImageRequest.setImage(image);
    annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(feature));
    visionRequests.add(annotateImageRequest);
}
```